# Kill off connections that are not consuming Rabbitmq

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq

I am having a bit of an issue where if the client crashes or if it loses connectivity it does not properly close the connection. This results in several idle connections that keep adding up. The client I am using rabbitmq-c does not support heartbeats yet therefore I cannot use that as a possible solution.

Is there anyway to kill off any connections that are not at the same time consuming a queue?

Comment: Do you mean close the connections on the server side? If so are the connections still appearing in the RabbitMQ management interface?

Comment: Yes exactly, and the connections are still appearing in the management interface.

Comment: Are you worried about connections or queues? Rabbit should eventually take care of broken connections. It might not be immediate, but it shouldn't take long (and is configurable). If you're worried about queues piling up set the auto-delete bit when you declare them and when all the connections for that queue close it'll clean itself up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the client was not setting a timeout time to the server therefore the connections were always being kept open. I also updated the client to support Heartbeats so there is now two ways the connections can be killed instead of being kept open.